# Safari address bar input matching history

Tags: macos, safari

I often visit an URL like aaa-test.com so it's in my history. I'm on Safari 14.0 Mac and Chrome Blink 85 stable on macOS Catalina.

If I type aaa in the address bar the full address appears in 'Top hit' and 'Bookmarks and History'. That's good.

Instead if I type aaa, aaa-test.com does appear in the dropdown. If I do same in Chrome, the URL appears.

Any way to change the behavior on Safari?

=====================edit===================

for example, this URL biocache-test.ala.org.au is in my history. If I type bi, safari can do auto-complete

[image]

But if I type test, no auto-complete (or whatever you call it)

[image]

Comment: Maybe I’m thick right now, but I don’t understand what you seek when the results are always appearing. Can you edit a screenshot of safari showing it not doing what you seek after you type aaa?